# Split a NumPy array of strings into 2 new NumPy arrays based on index positions provided by another NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This is my NumPy array:

```
og_arr = [['5mm', '45"', '300 mm WT', 'Nan'], ['50mm', '3/5"', 'Nan', 'Nan']]
```

I have written some logic that is able to identify at which index position the `mm/inch` string starts and this results in the following array.

```
 index_arr = [[1, 2, 4, -1], [2, 3, -1, -1]]
```

I would like to split `og_arr` into 2 arrays called `values` and `units` based on the `index_arr` so that I get the following.

```
# perform some sort of indexing + splitting operation involving og_arr and index_arr
values = [['5', '45', '300', 'Nan'], ['50', '3/5', 'Nan', 'Nan']]
units =  [['mm', '"', 'mm WT', ''], ['mm', '"', '', '']]
```

I have a solution to this problem using a `for/while` loop, however, I am more interested in finding out if a pure vectorized solution exists for this sort of problem.

Comment: I am not able to understand `index_arr`.. there is `4` in the index where we do not have index `4` in `og_arr`(it goes from 0 to 3)

Comment: I think the `index_arr` presents the start index of the units in the string. eg. `'300 mm WT'` in `index_arr` is `4`, which is `m`, and if the string is `Nan`, then return `-1` to index

Comment: Numpy offers little performance benefit over native Python in terms of string operations. Code syntax, maybe; speed, usually not.

Comment: @HMH1013 Yes, your assumption is bang on!

Comment: @QuangHoang, thank you for your input. Would you be able to provide me with a way to benchmark regular Python vs Numpy syntax on string operations?

Comment: [Numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html) has a list of vectorized string operations, notice the array's dtype. Your usecase can't really utilize any (combination of) those ops.

Comment: @QuangHoang, those `np.char` functions just apply python string methods to the elements of the array.  While they may be convenient, they don't "vectorize" anything.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought so as well. However the docs does say *vectorized*. I did not personally test this though.

Comment: You should probably split the (each of the) data after you got the individual index. I can't imagine a *vectorized* function that gets you that `index_arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With custom [vectorized](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function to split strings at given indices:

```
splitter = lambda x, idx: (x[:], '') if idx == -1 else (x[:idx], x[idx:])
v_splitter = np.vectorize(splitter)

values, units = v_splitter(og_arr, index_arr)
```

---

```
In [23]: values
Out[23]: 
array([['5', '45', '300 ', 'Nan'],
       ['50', '3/5', 'Nan', 'Nan']], dtype='<U5')

In [24]: units
Out[24]: 
array([['mm', '"', 'mm WT', ''],
       ['mm', '"', '', '']], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: `np.vectorized` is not vectorized. But then again, not important as this is string ops.

Comment: Why not just `valules, units = v_splitter(og_arr, index_arr)`?  It returns a tuple of arrays, no need to combine and resplit them.  This is a case where `vectorize` returning multiple arrays is useful.

Comment: @QuangHoang, `vectorize` may not give any performance advantage, but it does handle the 'nesting' of `og_arr` in a prettier way.

Comment: @hpaulj, indeed, I saw the intermediate results of `v_splitter` (when was testing it) and missed that it was quite sufficient. Thanks for recalling that

Comment: @hpaulj I did not say it's not convenient, I'm just stretching that it doesn't magically vectorize any function. Contrary to `numpy.char` functions, the docs specifically says there is no/little performance benifit over python loops.

Comment: @QuangHoang, a big thing that the `np.char` functions lack is taking substrings.   That is, they don't do anything like `astr[:4]`  I think there's a `split` on character, but not by length.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, that's what I commented under the question. As it is, this answer would be the best solution to the question; in terms of code cleanliness, not performance. `np.vectorized` is really a confusing name, might just be `np.map`.

Comment: @hpaulj btw, `str[:4]` would just be `.astype('<U4')`. But that's not what this question needs either.

Comment: @QuangHoang, what meant to say is that Roman's `splitter` function has to be applied, in one way or other, to each pair of `og` and `index` values.